# lookin for a way to load tiff image of a map to a matrix in order to do calculations

Tags: c#, image-processing, uwp

[image]

I have a picture that each pixel describes latitude (the brighter the pixel the higher the coordinate's latitude). my problem was that I couldn't find a way to transform this image to a 2D array of pixels. any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What format is your image in? A bitmap? some custom image format? What kind of 2D array do you want to convert it to? A multidimentional array, i.e. ushort[,]? Jagged array, i.e. ushort[][]? It is also fairly common to store 2D data in a linear array, i.e. ushort[] with some code to calculate the index from X/Y coordinates.

Comment: For what I know .tiff image are not natively supported in .Net , you need to convert it as Bitmap or load it through a third part library like TiffLibrary or BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET

Comment: the is image is tiff formatted if that's what you intended, I have thought about  storing the data in a linear array but I didn't knew how to calculate the index from X/Y coordinates. can you show me how to do it? or if you think that there is a an easier way to do it I don't really care I just need a data structure that I can extract data from with quick time complexity.

Comment: yeah I know that I converted the image to a bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the value of `BitmapDecoder.PixelWidth` and `BitmapDecoder.PixelHeight`, you could write two For loops to traverse the pixel data of the bitmap. The index of any pixel data is `array[x,y]`.

Please refer to the following code.

```
public async void Get()
    {
        StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        var imagefile=await folder.GetFileAsync("");
        var random = await RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(imagefile).OpenReadAsync();
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
        PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        var bytes = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
         var a = decoder.PixelWidth;
         var b = decoder.PixelHeight;
        Color[,] array= new Color[a,b];
        for (int x = 0; x < decoder.PixelWidth; x++)
        {             
            for (int y = 0; y < decoder.PixelHeight; y++)
            {
                var location = (y * (int)decoder.PixelWidth + x) * 3;
                Color color = Color.FromArgb(0, bytes[location + 0], bytes[location + 1], bytes[location + 2]);
                 array[x,y] = color;
               
            }
            
        }
    
    }
```